# SQL Query for Wordpress database

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I need some help in changing the postcontent.

I have used one of pulgin- automatic youtube posts. it created custom field 
"Youtube Video Code". "_tern_wp_youtube_video"

when ever i import, it adds youtube video code to the post custom filed.

I want this youtube code to add to postcontent as embed code

If Video code filed is not empty, then add

like this.

Comment: If Video code not empty, then create youtube iframe code and add to post content.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that in your single.php file where you want video to appear :

```
$myvideo = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_tern_wp_youtube_video',true);
if(!empty($myvideo)){
    echo '<iframe src="'.$myvideo.'"></iframe>';
}
```

You will maybe need to change the iframe code to fit with your needs.